# Do keras loss have to output one scalar per batch or one scalar for the whole batch ?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, loss-function

I read in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42895862/keras-why-do-loss-functions-have-to-return-one-scalar-per-batch-item-rather-tha) that keras custom loss function have to return one scalar per batch item.

I wrote a loss function that output a scalar for the whole batch and the network seems to converge. However I am not able to find any documentation on this or what exactly happens in the code. Is there a broadcasting done somewhere ? What happens if I add sample weights? Does someone has a pointer to where the magic happens ?

Thanks!

Comment: would be helpful for analysis to see your model code :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can often use a scalar in place of a vector and this will be interpreted as a vector that is filled with this value ( e.g 1 is interpreted as 1,1,1,1 ).
So if the result of your loss function for a batch is x, it is interpreted as if you were saying that loss for each item in the batch is x.

Comment: that's my guess but I'm looking for the exact code line where this could happen for confirmation

Comment: The exact line in implementation of Keras (or tensorflow), where the broadcasting is implemented?

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/545acc4b66b5fb0ed5457ef7288d836f022c118d/keras/engine/training.py#L340, this is where the total loss is calculated.